# How can I get VS Code to complete closing braces for Jinja bracket pairs?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I'm new to backend development with Python and Django. I'm watching tutorial videos, and I'm noticing something when they insert a Jinja block.

Every time they insert `%` within a `{}`, it adds another `%` to complete the block. This is what happens when I insert a `(`, and VS Code automatically adds a `)` to complete it. How come it's not doing the same for `%` within a `{}`? How can I add this functionality to VS Code so I don't have to add the second % every time to cut down on repetition?

Comment: you can write a simple extension to do that, but keep track of the added characters when the user deletes the starting `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably coming from an extension that you just don't have installed. I see https://github.com/wholroyd/vscode-jinja/blob/master/jinja.configuration.json and https://github.com/samuelcolvin/jinjahtml-vscode/blob/main/language-configuration.json. So try installing [`wholroyd.jinja`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wholroyd.jinja) or [`samuelcolvin.jinjahtml`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with those extensions)</sub></sup>.

The asker states that they solved their problem by putting the following in their settings.json (which uses the [`monosans.djlint`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint) extension):

```json
"[html][django-html][handlebars][hbs][mustache][jinja][jinja-html][nj][njk][nunjucks][twig]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
},
```

Comment: I did some editing in settings.json by adding     `"[html][django-html][handlebars][hbs][mustache][jinja][jinja-html][nj][njk][nunjucks][twig]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint",
    },`. It works now.